# Send SMTP mail when an exception occurs

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I'd be grateful if someone could tell me if I'm on the right track...  Basically, I have a webservice i need to run for my app, I've put it into a try catch, if the try fails I want the catch to send me an email message with the details of the exception.

```
try
{
    // run webservice here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string strTo = "scott@...";
    string strFrom = "web@...";
    string strSubject = "Webservice Not Run";
    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "thepostoffice";

    SmtpMail.Send(strFrom, strTo, strSubject, ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Yeah, have you tested your code? Do you get errors? If so, what are the messages? You're leaving us in the dark here...

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Yes, but what happens if the email fails?  You should consider a more robust error handling implementation using a third part tool, such as Microsoft's Enterprise Library Logging, NLog, etc.

Comment: Error Message is "The transport failed to connect to the server." so i guess i will have to look at my smtpserver settings!

Comment: Yeah, but I don't see you sending your credentials, and they are required too...  smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are but you'd better wrapp yor exception handler in some kind of logger or use existing ones like [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).

Comment: +1, Much better to use Libraries than rolling out your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way to send emails whenever an Exception occurs can be done like this:

```
        SmtpClient Server = new SmtpClient();
        Server.Host = ""; //example: smtp.gmail.com
        Server.Port = ; //example: 587 if you're using gmail
        Server.EnableSsl = true; //If the smtp server requires it

        //Server Credentials
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential();
        credentials.UserName = "youremail@gmail.com";
        credentials.Password = "your password here";
        //assign the credential details to server
        Server.Credentials = credentials;

        //create sender's address
        MailAddress sender = new MailAddress("Sender email address", "sender name");

        //create receiver's address
        MailAddress receiver = new MailAddress("receiver email address", "receiver name");

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(sender, receiver);
        message.Subject = "Your Subject";
        message.Body = ex.ToString();
        //send the email
        Server.Send(message);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes this the right way, if you don't want to use any logger tool.You can create function SendMail(string Exceptioin) to one of the your common class and than call this function from each catch block

Comment: aside from the misspellings in your post, can you provide a bit of sample code that demonstrates how to do this?

Comment: you can edit the spelling mistake @jcolebrand, I wil update some sample also ..coming soon